# How can I change my number validation from a form to a prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

So currently I have this code:

```
<html>
<title>Number Seperation</title>
<body>
    <p>Please enter as many numbers in the box below as you wish.
    <br>
    Make sure to seperate each different number by hitting the submit button.</p>

    <form>
        <script>
                function isNumberKey(evt){
                    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                        return false;
                    return true;
                }
        </script>
      <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Which has a text box where you can input only numbers. 
I would like to know how to change the text box to a prompt window while still keeping the validation check to ensure only numbers are accepted. 
How would I do this?

Comment: A prompt is blocking, there's no way to validate the input before the prompt is closed and the value returned. Prompts are generally a horrible idea for a website in 2015, when so many nice alternatives excists.

Comment: @adeneo well I'm not allowed to use php or any other langauges so I need to do the validation somehow and also print the values that are entered. So how would I do that keeping it in the same format? The teacher recommended the prompt which is the reason for the question.

Comment: If you use the `prompt()` function you'd store its return value (what the user entered) in a variable, and you can then test the content of that variable any way you like. I wouldn't use a `prompt()` in the first place, but to validate the contents of the variable I'd probably use a regular expression. Do you expect users to enter one number at a time, or type multiple numbers into the same `prompt()`, separated by spaces or commas or something?

Comment: Here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/8bwbh4rf/**

Comment: Why not use something more modern? Very basic plugin like jQuery dialog is better than an alert. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6rsc3xcr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tied the getInput method to the button. window.prompt pops up the input dialog. I used isNaN() to check whether it's (not) a number, but you can customize to your need. Then I'm concatenating it into the list element.

```js
function getInput(){
                var input = window.prompt("Enter a number");
                if(isNaN(input))
                  alert('That was not a number')
                else {
                  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "<li>" + input + "</li>";
                }                
                
              }
```

```html
<html>
<title>Number Seperation</title>

<body>
  <p>Please enter as many numbers in the box below as you wish.
    <br>Make sure to seperate each different number by hitting the submit button.</p>

  <form>
  
    <input type="button" onclick="getInput()" value="Supply number" />
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</body>
```

References for things I used:

- [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp)
- [Javascript pop-up boxes (see Prompt Box)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)
- [HTML DOM methods (see getElementById and innerHTML)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp)